# Extract from sum only terms with exponents satisfying a specific condition

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, approximation

Consider an equation

```
eq = x1^n x2^m s^a+ c+ x1^g s^r x2^l+..so on
```

n, m, a, g, r and l are known real numbers and equation contain lots of these terms. I want to find a new equation from above equation by ignoring terms in which sum of the power of x1, x2 and s is bigger than 4. for example in the first term, if n+a+m is bigger than 4, this term should be ignored. How can I do that? an answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce a dummy variable and use `Series`

```
eq = Expand[(1 + x1^2 + x2^3) (1 + x1 + x2) (1 + x3)];
Normal[Series[eq /. u : (x1 | x2 | x3) -> ϵ u, {ϵ, 0, 4}]] /. ϵ -> 1
(* 1 + x1 + x1^2 + x1^3 + x2 + x1^2 x2 + x2^3 + x1 x2^3 + x2^4 + x3 + 
 x1 x3 + x1^2 x3 + x1^3 x3 + x2 x3 + x1^2 x2 x3 + x2^3 x3 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `Cases`:

```
expr = 1/2 a^0.1 b^1.2 c^2.5 + 2 a^1.1 b^4.2124 c^7.01;
Plus @@ Cases[
    expr,
    Times[___, Power[a, pa_], Power[b, pb_], Power[c, pc_]] /; 
        pa + pb + pc < 4
  ]
(* Out[10]= 1/2 a^0.1 b^1.2 c^2.5 *)
```